# Shabang Line For Python Script With Conda

Tags: python, pip, conda

I'm trying to write my Python script to run in a particular *conda* environment without relying on the user to do it correctly.  If the environment is named *MyEnv*, for example, the following [shabang line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/399690/multiple-arguments-in-shebang) will do that.

```bash
#!/bin/env -S /my-conda-stuff/bin/conda run -n MyEnv --live-stream python
```

Is it necessary though?  Does it add anything to more simply just specifying the location of that environment's Python?

```bash
#!/my-conda-stuff/envs/MyEnv/bin/python
```

I ask because using `pip install` to install my software rewrites my shabang line from the former to the latter.  Are they equivalent?  I know the first [sets environment variables](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#activating-an-environment) like `$PATH` that the second doesn't, but my program doesn't use those.  I don't want to undo the "favor" `pip install` did for me unless I have to.

Thanks.

Comment: If you're specifying the entire path anyway, then `/bin/env` doesn't gain you anything.  I don't know why they want to run "conda" instead of "python".

Comment: Yeah, the ```/bin/env -S``` part is a bit obscure.  My first link explains it, but to summarize, it's needed to split the argument list on whitespace.  On my RedHat 8 Enterprise Linux operating system, shabang lines are split only once, at the first whitespace.  The first word is the command that will be run, and everything else is passed as a single argument, followed by the file name.  ```conda``` wouldn't know what to do with ```"run -n MyEnv..."``` as its first argument, but ```/bin/env``` with ```-S``` splits as we intended.  This behavior of ```exec``` isn't universal but is common.